# Persisting "Docker Compose" settings in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose

I've been following the guidance from Microsoft regarding using the Docker tools in Visual Studio as described in the following links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/containerized-lifecycle-architecture/design-develop-containerized-apps/visual-studio-tools-for-docker
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker?view=aspnetcore-2.2

I have a solution that contains my web program project, and a docker-compose project.  When I debug the program, it runs a debugger instance called "Docker Compose" that was created by Visual Studio when I added the docker-compose project.  Here is a screenshot of the debug toolbar:

[image: VS Debug Toolbar - Docker Compose]

When I check it into source control, the docker-compose files are included into git as expected:

- docker-compose.dcproj
- docker-compose.override.yml
- docker-compose.yml
- .dockerignore

However, when I re-clone the repository and start fresh, the "Docker Compose" debugger is not available.  Instead, there is a "Docker" debugger, that appears to ignore the "docker-compose" project when it starts.

[image: VS Debug Toolbar - Docker]

When running this debugger, it only does the build for the basic docker container, but not the docker-compose stuff, which makes it not functional for local testing/debugging.

The only way I've found to get the "Docker Compose" debugger back, is to do one of the following:

- Check the ".vs" folder into source control.  **YUCK! - *Not an option*.**

**OR**

- Upon cloning, and after opening the solution in Visual Studio:

  1. "Remove" the "docker-compose" project from the solution.  Do NOT delete the files from disk.
  2. Re-add "Orchestration Container Support" to the project.  This will recreate the docker-compose project in the solution.  Answer "No" to all "overwrite files" requests, to keep the existing files intact.  This appears to also recreate the default "Docker Compose" debugger in Visual Studio.

Ideally, I want my teammates to be able to clone the solution, and just run it.  Is there a best practice recommendation for getting these Visual Studio settings into source control so that other team members don't have to perform manual steps to get the project running?

Is this a bug with the Visual Studio Docker Tools?  It seems to me that if the solution contains a docker-compose project, Visual Studio should know how to handle it.